# No matching provisioning profiles found for application

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I make cocos2d project in mac i mean in xcode, now i have make IPA from this project but i cannot do that.

My error is com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers. please help me for solving that

I have try making new and new provisioning profile but i cannot get success.

What is the error, error in making provisioning profile or error in cocos2d project.

Please check this screenshot http://prntscr.com/51l9rr

Comment: You need to be enrolled on a paid developer program to generate a provisioning profile and signing certificates to run your app on a provisioned device.

Comment: I have this but after making build apps is not install successful on device